# ng2-table angular2 rc4 HTML tags

Tags: html, angular

I have a angular2 component which is generating data to populate my ng2-table, but I cannot seem to put HTML tags into a cell. Instead the cell renders as such:

[image]

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table/issues/51

I've tried to modify the js file that is coming down as indicated as an older fix but changing the markup to the [innerHtml] angular2 element does not appear to be accepted.

It seems that others are having this problem as well, has anyone else found a solution?  I'm aware that ag-grid is capable of doing this, but we need to use ng2-table as it supports bootstrap pagination which ag-grid does not appear to.

Comment: Please share your code, so it's possible for us to help you :)

Comment: Hi @RasmusGlenvig, My apologies but I'm honestly not too familiar with how to setup a plunker, but my code is essentially not much different from the example code listed here [link](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) simply replace an entry in the table-data.ts file and you **should** run into the same issue I am.

Comment: There are a fork with this feature (https://github.com/jdelgadoalfonso/ng2-table). Although I think that doesn't good idea use a fork only for this feature.